# html5audio plugin in CKEditor 4 in vue

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to add the html5audio plugin in my ckeditor 4 in vue but everytime I am getting *html5audio are not found ....*. I have two questions. First of all, can html5audio plugin be installed in **  "ckeditor4-vue": "^1.0.1"**. Second one, is there any plugin where I can add html5 audio link in my vue project?